# Kotlin loop with irregular steps

Tags: java, kotlin

I have been trying to translate a Java for expression into Kotlin which produces this sequence:

> 1,2,4,8,16,32,64

This is the Java code:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i = i + i) {
    System.out.printf("%d,", i);
}
```

The only way I have found to translate this into Kotlin is:

```
var i = 1
while (i < 100) {
    print("$i,")
    i += i
}
```

I have tried to use step expressions, but this does not seem to work. Is there any way to express this type of sequence more elegantly in Kotlin?

I know you can have code like this one using Kotlin + Java 9:

```
Stream.iterate(1, { it <= 100 }) { it!! + it }.forEach { print("$it,") }
```

But this relies on Java libraries and I would prefer Kotlin native libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `generateSequence` function to create an infinite sequence, then use `takeWhile` to limit it at a specific value and then use `forEach` instead of a `for-in` construct to handle each iteration:

`generateSequence(1) { it + it }.takeWhile { it < 100 }.forEach { print("$it,") }`